# Split Variable and insert NA's in between

Tags: r, variables, split, dataframe

I have a variable which looks like this:

```
Var
[1] 3, 4, 5     2, 4, 5     2, 4     1, 4, 5
```

I need to split it into a dataframe which looks like this:

```
V1   V2   V3   V4   V5
NA   NA   3    4    5
NA   2    NA   4    5
NA   2    NA   4    NA
1    NA   NA   4    5
```

Unfortunatley, I couldnt find a post which solves my problem. Does anyone know how I could do that?
Thank you very much in advance!

Edit: I found a solution based on your answers and posted it below.

Edit2: I improved the efficiency of my code with Ananda's solution.

Comment: Is `Var` a `list` or a `vector` or what? Your example is not reproducible. Is it `c(3,4,5,2,4,5,2,4,1,4,5)` or `list(c(3,4,5),c(2,4,5),c(2,4),c(1,4,5))` or `c("3, 4, 5     2, 4, 5     2, 4     1, 4, 5")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the OPs answer, "var" is a string, like:

```
var <- c("3, 4, 5", "2, 4, 5", "2, 4", "1, 4, 5")
```

If that is the case, you can consider `cSplit_e` from my "splitstackshape" package:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit_e(data.frame(var), "var", ",", mode = "value", drop = TRUE)
#   var_1 var_2 var_3 var_4 var_5
# 1    NA    NA     3     4     5
# 2    NA     2    NA     4     5
# 3    NA     2    NA     4    NA
# 4     1    NA    NA     4     5
```

If it is a `list`, as the other answers have assumed, you can use the (non-exported) `numMat` function in "splitstackshape" that powers `cSplit_e`.

```
var <- list(c(3,4,5), c(2,4,5), c(2,4), c(1,4,5))
splitstackshape:::numMat(var, mode = "value")
#       1  2  3 4  5
# [1,] NA NA  3 4  5
# [2,] NA  2 NA 4  5
# [3,] NA  2 NA 4 NA
# [4,]  1 NA NA 4  5
```

Under the hood, `numMat` is a very similar approach to that used in @thelatemail's answer.

---

If you have -99 representing `NA` and you want to exclude them, you can try:

```
var <- c("3, 4, 5", "2, -99, 4, 5", "2, 4", "1, 4, 5, -99")
splitstackshape:::numMat(
  lapply(strsplit(var, ","), function(x) as.numeric(x)[as.numeric(x) > 0]), 
  mode = "value")
#       1  2  3 4  5
# [1,] NA NA  3 4  5
# [2,] NA  2 NA 4  5
# [3,] NA  2 NA 4 NA
# [4,]  1 NA NA 4  5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your first solution worked very well and made my code much shorter!

Answer (score 5):

Using matrix indexing:

```
Var <- list(c(3,4,5),c(2,4,5),c(2,4),c(1,4,5))
unVar <- unlist(Var)
out <- matrix(NA, nrow=length(Var), ncol=max(unVar))

out[cbind(rep(seq_along(Var),sapply(Var,length)),unVar)] <- unVar
# and if you're using the new version of R, you can simplify a little:
out[cbind(rep(seq_along(Var),lengths(Var)),unVar)] <- unVar

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]   NA   NA    3    4    5
#[2,]   NA    2   NA    4    5
#[3,]   NA    2   NA    4   NA
#[4,]    1   NA   NA    4    5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Var <- list(c(3, 4, 5), c(2, 4, 5), c(2, 4), c(1, 4, 5))
 M <- matrix(NA, nrow=length(Var), ncol=max(sapply(Var,max)))
 for( L in seq(Var) ) { M [ cbind( rep( L, length(Var[[L]])), Var[[L]]) ] <- Var[[L]]}
 M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   NA   NA    3    4    5
[2,]   NA    2   NA    4    5
[3,]   NA    2   NA    4   NA
[4,]    1   NA   NA    4    5
```

Personally my vote recommendation is  thelatemail's version which is basically isomorphic to this.

Answer (score 0):

If Var is just a vector then I would do the following:

```
Var = c(3,4,5,2,4,5,2,4,1,4,5)
RowIdx = c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3),rep(3,2),rep(4,3))
DF = matrix(NA,nrow=4,ncol=5)

for (idx in 1:length(Var)){
  DF[RowIdx[idx],Var[idx]] = Var[idx]
}
```

Of course if you had a lot more data you might want to find a way to generate the row indices in a more automated way

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution based on your responses! My final solution looks like follows:

```
# I had the additional problem that my variable was a factor, therefore I had to transform it first.
df <- data.frame(Var)
Var <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$Var), ", "), "[")
for(i in 1:length(Var)){
  Var[[i]] <- as.numeric(Var[[i]]) 
}

# Then I created a matrix based on thelatemails and BondedDusts approach.
M <- matrix(NA, nrow=length(Var), ncol=max(sapply(Var,max)))

# Additionally, I had the problem that there were some lines with a single -99, which indicates a missing value for the complete line. I had some problems with this negative value. For this reason, I assigned NA's first.
for(i in 1:length(Var)){
  Var[[i]][Var[[i]] == -99] <- NA
}

# Final assignment like suggested by BonedDust.
for( L in seq(Var) ) { M [ cbind( rep( L, length(Var[[L]])), Var[[L]]) ] <- Var[[L]]}
M
```

Im not sure if this is the fastest solution, but everything works fine now! Thank you very much for the fast and extensive answers!